# Editing/Replacing content in multiple files in Unix AIX without opening it

Tags: unix, rename, vi

I have multiple files in Unix directory.
files names are as below.
    EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part1.expd
    EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part2.expd
    EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part3.expd

In each of the above file there is a common line like below. eg

```
EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part1.expd
```

is having below data

```
Log=EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part1.log  
file=EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part1.lst  

EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part2.expd
```

is having below data

```
Log=EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part2.log  
file=EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_10022012_0630_Part2.lst
```

I want to replace the **10022012_0630** from EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part*.expd files with **22052013_1000** without actully opening those files. Changes should happen in all EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part*.expdp files in a directory at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean you don't want to *manually* open the files:

```
sed -i 's/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/' filename*.log
```

---

**update:** since the "-i" switch is not available on AIX, but assuming you have ksh (or a compatible shell):

```
mkdir modified
for file in filename*.log; do
    sed 's/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/' "$file" > modified/"$file"
done
```

Now the modified files will be in the `modified` directory.

Comment: Hi I have specified my requirements. COuld you please help now

Comment: `sed` is a command you can use in your shell, outside of vi. To find out more about it, try typing `man sed`. If I understand your situation, just take my answer and replace "filename*.log" with "EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part*.expd".

Comment: I am not able to use -i option on my clients matchine... is there any other way??

Comment: Hi.. This one rocks and I got whatever I wanted.. cool mate.. thanks a lot.. it worked.. (y)

Comment: There is nothing `ksh`-specific in the `for` loop.  Any Bourne-compatible shell should understand that code. (If you are new to shells, that means e.g. `sh`, `zsh`, and `bash`, but not `csh` or its derivative `tcsh`.)

Comment: @tripleee Right, I mentioned ksh because it is an old Bourne-compatible shell that is available on old versions of AIX.

Answer (score 0):

It's some kind of extreme optimist who suggests `sed -i` on AIX.

It's a bit more likely that perl will be installed.

```
perl -pi -e 's/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/' EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part*.expd
```

If no perl, then you'll just have to do it like a Real Man:

```
for i in EnvName.Fullbkp.schema_121212_1212_Part*.expd
do
  ed -s "$i" <<'__EOF'
1,$s/10022012_0630/22052013_1000/g
wq
__EOF
done
```

Have some backups ready before trying these.